# PHP - error in json_encode()

Tags: php, json

Problem: returns array, but not in json.

Result: must return array with in array. outer array has key with numbers and value is array with keys "ID" and "NAME" and there values are assigned from database.

```
$i = 0;
$json_values = array();
while($sctg = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_sctg)){
    $json_values[$i] = array("ID" => $sctg['ID'], "NAME" => $sctg['NAME']);
    $i++;
}
echo json_encode($json_values);
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem? The code looks perfectly fine.

Comment: Problem: returns array, but not in json.

if I take out variable "$i" as a key - it return as json, but if I use "$i" as key - it returns array, but not in json

Comment: Can you please include the actual and the desired output?

Comment: Hey - if my first key is 0 it return in not json, but if my key is 1 or greater - works fine! any clues why?

Comment: I'm sure it **does** return JSON. You probably just **think** it doesn't. Please **post the output**.

Comment: And you wanna read about associative arrays in javascript here: http://blog.xkoder.com/2008/07/10/javascript-associative-arrays-demystified/

Comment: output: [{"ID":"4","NAME":"asdasd"},{"ID":"3","NAME":"LOKS"},{"ID":"1","NAME":"LOL"}]

as you can see it doesn't  show $json_values keys

Comment: So what exactly is wrong with this? It is an array that contains objects (like associative arrays) for your rows. That's exactly what you want - isn't it? You can iterate over the rows using a for loop: `for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { var row = data[i]; alert(row.NAME); }` - Actually, it is important that you get an array and not an object for the top-level element since object keys are not ordered in JavaScript. So you couldn't be sure the rows are in the same order you received them from the database if they weren't stored in an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is perfectly fine - you just misunderstood the different between arrays and objects in JavaScript.

```
[{"ID":"4","NAME":"asdasd"},
 {"ID":"3","NAME":"LOKS"},
 {"ID":"1","NAME":"LOL"}]
```

This is JSON containing an array with three elements. Each element is an object with the properties `ID` and `NAME`.

Let's assume that array is stored in `data`. You can iterate over the objects in that array with a simple `for` loop:

```
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var row = data[i];
    // Here you can use row.ID and row.NAME
}
```

---

I guess you expected your JSON to look like this:

```
{
    0: {"ID":"4","NAME":"asdasd"},
    1: {"ID":"3","NAME":"LOKS"},
    2: {"ID":"1","NAME":"LOL"}
}
```

This would actually be **bad** since objects in JavaScript are **not ordered** (even though they actually are in most browsers, but that's not guaranteed!). So when iterating over the rows in such an element (using `for(var key in data)`), you would not necessarily get the row with ID=4 first just because its key is zero.

However, if you really want an object instead of an array for some reason (you don't!), you could always cast the array to object:

```
echo json_encode((object)$json_values);
```

As a side-note, usually it's a good idea to have an object as the top-level element in JSON for security reasons (you can redefine the array constructor and then include something with a top-level array with a script tag and thus access data usually protected by the same origin policy if it was accessed by an XHR request), so I'd change the PHP code like this:

```
echo json_encode(array('rows' => $json_values));
```

Comment: Sorry for big confusion that I made - I didn't explained my problem as well as I needed. New guy.. :) Anyway - after your post I realised my ACTUAL problem - OBJECTS.
So I found solution for my problem!
echo json_encode($json_values, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);

Comment: Are you sure you want that? Unless you use the row id as the key it does not make much sense to use objects instead of arrays!

Answer (score 0):

No need to use  `$i++;` directly use

```
while($sctg = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_sctg)){
    $json_values[] = array("ID" => $sctg['ID'], "NAME" => $sctg['NAME']);    
}
```

and it will return you the JSON

Comment: No need to use $i++; - true! but still no json!
I see that problem is with $json_values key!